# Concatenate dataframe to a master dataframe only if the the values do not exist in the master dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have 2 dataframes:

```
Df1 = 

  Batch  Result
0     A       3
1     A       5
2     B       5
3     B       6
4     C       8
5     C       3


Df2=

  Batch  Result
0     C       8
1     C       3
2     D       6
3     D       1
```

I want to concat Df2 to Df1, but I only want to have batch D from Df2 in Df1. The output should be look like this:

```
Df1 = 

  Batch  Result
0     A       3
1     A       5
2     B       5
3     B       6
4     C       8
5     C       3
2     D       6
3     D       1
```

How can I do this with Pandas?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yeah got it by your answer, I think the example mentioned in the question is not appropriate, or in other words, doesn't take care of the scenario that OP mentions.

Comment: @ThePyGuy no that will not work.

Comment: @Hertyuw yeah Got it, Retracted the duplicate flag back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the batch that are in `Df1` from `Df2` before concat:

```
pd.concat([Df1, Df2[ ~Df2['Batch'].isin(Df1['Batch'])] ])
```